# How do I detect functions that I can apply tail call optimisation to?

Tags: lisp, scheme, tail-call-optimization

I'm trying to write a Scheme interpreter, but finding TCO difficult to implement. I'm not sure what properties a function must have in order for TCO to kick in.

1) A function with a self-recursive call at the end of the definition:

```
(define (sum-list list accum)
  (if (null list) accum
      (sum-list (cdr list) (+ accum 1))))
```

2) A function with a self-recursive call that isn't at the end of the definition:

```
(define (sum-list list accum)
  (cond ((not (null list))
         (sum-list (cdr list) (+ accum 1)))
        (else accum)))
```

3) A function that stores the recursive call in a variable before returning it:

```
(define (sum-list list accum)
  (let ((sum
         (if (null list)
             accum
             (sum-list (cdr list (+ accum 1))))))
    sum))
```

4) Mutually recursive functions:

```
(define (sum-list list accum)
  (if (null list)
      accum
      (other-function (cdr list) (+ accum 1))))

(define (other-function list accum)
  (sum-list list accum))
```

5) Simply calling another unrelated function at the end of the function definition:

```
(define (foo)
  (bar))
```

6) The trickiest case I can think of is closures. What if I hold on to a reference to a variable in scope?

```
(define (sum-list list accum ignored)
  (let ((local-var 12345))
    (if (null list)
        accum
        (sum-list
         (cdr list)
         (+ accum 1)
         (lambda () local-var)))))
```

7) Calling another function at the end of the function definition, with a self-recursive call as an argument:

```
(define (sum-list list)
  (if (null list)
      0
      (+ 1 (sum-list (cdr list)))))
```

As I understand it, TCO implementations (in both Scheme and Common Lisp) rewrite TCO-friendly functions, so they must be able to statically detect TCO-friendly functions.

What I'd like to know is:

- Which of these functions would be rewritten by TCO, and why only those?
- Are the circumstances (e.g. 7) where the TCO rewriting occurs, but the function still consumes memory linearly?

Comment: Any call whose result value is directly returned by a function is a tail call.

Comment: If you're implementing a genuine Scheme, then [Óscar López's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18818128/1281433) is most appropriate;  the Scheme standard(s) define what is an what isn't a call in tail position.  You don't need to try to enumerate these cases on your own;  the standard(s) have already done it for you.  [Sylwester's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18818200/1281433) might be a useful implementation approach, as long as you can guarantee that following that approach covers the cases that the standard(s) describe.

Comment: Your case (3) is explicitly mentioned in the standard that Óscar López cited: “Note:‌ Implementations may recognize that some non-tail calls … can be evaluated as though they were tail calls. In the example above, the let expression could be compiled as a tail call … .” (See the code in the standard for the code they're talking about.  It's the same type of example, though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the Scheme specification, all the possible tail contexts are defined there. In particular, in R6RS (the current ratified standard) you should check section [§11.20 Tail calls and tail contexts](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_sec_11.20):

> A *tail call* is a procedure call that occurs in a *tail context*. Tail contexts are defined inductively. Note that a tail context is always determined with respect to a particular lambda expression.
>
> - The last expression within the body of a lambda expression, shown as <tail expression> below, occurs in a tail context.
>
>   ```
>   (lambda <formals>
>     <definition>* 
>     <expression>* <tail expression>)
>   ```
> - If one of the following expressions is in a tail context, then the subexpressions shown as <tail expression> are in a tail context. These were derived from specifications of the syntax of the forms described in this chapter by replacing some occurrences of <expression> with <tail expression>. Only those rules that contain tail contexts are shown here.
>
>   ```
>   (if <expression> <tail expression> <tail expression>)
>   (if <expression> <tail expression>)
>
>   (cond <cond clause>+)
>   (cond <cond clause>* (else <tail sequence>))
>
>   (case <expression>
>     <case clause>+)
>   (case <expression>
>     <case clause>*
>     (else <tail sequence>))
>
>   (and <expression>* <tail expression>)
>   (or <expression>* <tail expression>)
>
>   (let <bindings> <tail body>)
>   (let <variable> <bindings> <tail body>)
>   (let* <bindings> <tail body>)
>   (letrec* <bindings> <tail body>)
>   (letrec <bindings> <tail body>)
>   (let-values <mv-bindings> <tail body>)
>   (let*-values <mv-bindings> <tail body>)
>
>   (let-syntax <bindings> <tail body>)
>   (letrec-syntax <bindings> <tail body>)
>
>   (begin <tail sequence>)
>   ```
>
>   A <cond clause> is `(<test> <tail sequence>)`, a <case clause> is `((<datum>*) <tail sequence>)`, a <tail body> is `<definition>* <tail sequence>`, and a <tail sequence> is `<expression>* <tail expression>`.
> - If a `cond` expression is in a tail context, and has a clause of the form `(<expression1> => <expression2>)` then the (implied) call to the procedure that results from the evaluation of <expression<sub>2</sub>> is in a tail context. <Expression<sub>2</sub>> itself is not in a tail context.

Comment: I was going to post something similar to this.  Do you think you could quote the relevant section here, in case that link should ever go dead?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor just look for "tail call" in the table of contents, in R6RS is section 11.20, the number might change but there will always be at least one section in the Scheme specification devoted to tail call - it's such an important part of the language!

Comment: Oh yes, the section is easy to find;  my opinion is just that the answer better stands on its own if the relevant text (or, in this case, since the second of the two cases is a big list, at least part of it) is quoted.  I'm not really all that worried about R6RS becoming completely unavailable.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor ok, got it

Answer (score 7):

You haven't mentioned what runtime or language this is going to interpret Scheme so it might be that this answer is a little off.

The fool proof way of implementing tail call optimization and get call/cc in the same time is to do CPS-conversion. With CPS, every call is a tail call and non-tail recursive code gets nested continuations.

TCO you'll get when you pop the stack before applying the tail call. Since every call is a tail call in CPS you know what to do.

Every of your procedures would benefit from this except 3 and 7. Those has a continuation to do when the recursive call returns.

**EDIT Python:**

Python doesn't have TCO so you cannot use the host language to do calls directly. You could, however, [do it with trampolines](http://www.usrsb.in/blog/blog/2012/08/12/bouncing-pythons-generators-with-a-trampoline/).

Comment: I'm implementing my interpreter in Python, which gives me built-in closure support but no TCO in the host language.

Comment: @WilfredHughes With trampolines you can do TCO in a python host. se my addition to my asnwer.